# Jesey Oauth client and "%20" spaces

Tags: twitter, oauth, jersey

HI all.  I am trying to use the Sun Jersey Client API with Jesey Oauth to connect to twitter.  Lets say I already have the oauth token and token secret.

```
String accessToken = MY_TOKEN;
String accessTokenSecret = MY_TOKEN_SECRET;
String url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml";

// initialize the params and secret.
OAuthParameters params = initOAuthParams();
params.token(accessToken);
OAuthSecrets secrets = initOAuthSecrets();
secrets.tokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);

// now access the resource
OAuthClientFilter filter = getClientFilter(params, secrets);
WebResource resource = client.resource(url);
resource.addFilter(filter);

MultivaluedMapImpl form = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
String status = new String("test with spaces");
form.add("status", status);

// post it
resource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(String.class, form);
```

This code will work, but the spaces are encoded as "+".  That would normally be fine, but Twitter seems to only take "%20".  if I try replacing the post with

```
resource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(String.class, "status=test with spaces");
```

or

```
resource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(String.class, "status=test%20with%20spaces");
```

twitter will respond with a 401, Incorrect Signature.  If I try just

```
resource.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(String.class, "status=test");
```

twitter will accept it.  How can I get Oauth to work with spaces encoded as "%20"?

Thanks!
Mason

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in jersey 1.3
https://jersey.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=511
https://jersey.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=433

but we are running into the same problem.

A simple net.oauth.client.OAuthClient does the job